# Why is my circuit working only when I touch it?

Tags: led, arduino-pro-micro, transistor

I have connected digital pin 2 of arduino to the circuit as shown:
[image: pin 2 to 1kOhm resistor to base of 2N222 transistor. Emitter to -ve of 9v battery. Collector to -ve of LED, +ve of LED to 330Ohm resistor, resistor to +9v]
The problem is that the LED is not turning on normally its only turning on when I touch anything on collector side of circuit. What seems to be the reason? Seems like grounding problem as its turning off when I don't touch my legs to ground.
[image: turns on when I touch it]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: if that's an npn, it's (probably) backwards. you also need to common the ground with the MCU

Comment: Hint: Use wires intended for breadboards. The battery wires lack pins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you have guessed it: although it's very hard to say from those photos, it doesn't look like you have the circuit grounded.

Connect a ground from the Arduino to the black wire from the battery.

Comment: Yes, you are right its working now. Thank you very much :D.

Comment: Sorry for the photos, I uploaded this from my phone and I put connections in image descriptions, but they are not visible in the post.